# Css, Can I use negative padding so that together with a border they appear outside the container?

Tags: css

What I’m trying to achieve is a top border that matches up (i.e. overlaps) exactly with the bottom border of an element above.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: can show some code to understand better ?

Answer (score 6):

Negative padding is not allowed, nor in the CSS spec as far as I'm aware. Padding is for adjustments within the box model, margin is for adjustments *outside*.

You may be able to achieve the desired affect with a negative margin

`margin-top:-20px;`

for instance.

But it would help to see your code to offer more assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, but not with padding. Use a negative top margin instead.

See http://jsfiddle.net/TD9x7/

Answer (score 0):

either you use negative margins or absolute positioning. negative values are not allowed

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use negative padding so that together with a border they appear outside the container

No, but you can use negative margin. Anyway, I'd set only left and right border of inner element.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can easily be solved without messing with the margin/padding, just remove the bottom border, which will make it look as if it was overlapping.

```
border-bottom:none;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E9XHA/

If your borders are side by side just remove the right/left border... etc